# Using BOTH Href & click listener

Tags: javascript, anchor, href, addeventlistener

I've got a browser plug-in I'm working on and I want it to behave a certain way when the user clicks things.  Not limited to, but including, a behavior for links!

The problem is that the plug-in has to work for a wide variety of sites, and some of those sites use the dreaded pseudo-protocol such as:
`<a href="javascript: showSomeElement();">Show Element</a>`

Currently my behavior is added to the anchor tag via
`anchor.addEventListener('click', superAwesomeFunction);`

Unfortunately this has a problem where the click listener only fires once.  If I `preventDefault()` of course the click listener sticks around, but I've now broken the host site!  Otherwise, clicking the link fires the click listener but only on the first click.  I'm wondering why my superAwesomeFunction() doesn't fire again if the link is clicked a second time.  Is `href="javascript:things()"` doing more than I know?

Comment: Does the `<a>` element get replaced?

Comment: When I was testing with Firebug, no it does not get replaced.

Comment: Your description is kind of confusing.  is superAwesomeFunction not firing, but showSomeElement is?

Comment: Both fire, but only the first time the link is clicked.  The second time it's clicked, only shoeSomeElement fires.

Comment: Trying to help, but I can't replicate. Perhaps you can tweak this fiddle to be more like your situation: http://jsfiddle.net/97Hy7/

Comment: Fiddle updated...but not reproducing the problem.

Comment: I'm going to have to take a look at the showSomeElement() function and make sure it's as innocuous as it seems.  Unfortunately I won't have that opportunity until tomorrow.

Comment: Ultimately it was the one thing I was absolutely certain it was not.  The host site I was testing against did one of the dumbest javascript moves I've seen.  He(or She) was Searching for the parent <span> tag based on it's ID, taking it's .html() then doing a .replace("show", "hide") and writing that into the span (using JQuery no less!).  I saw the same HTML I modified in the same place because I didn't think to test for 'wtf', which is my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add an event listener to a link that has a JavaScript function call set in the `href` attribute.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshearl/sGR58/2/) that shows it working. Both functions fire each time the link is clicked.

There must be something else going on with your code beyond what we can see in what you gave us.

Comment: I'm thinking more and more this must be the case.  For now, I'm going to make this the answer.  I'll follow up if there's more at play, when I have an opportunity to get deeper into this tomorrow.

Comment: Following up in history!  You were absolutely correct the problem was that the host site would replace the node with a new node that was an exact duplicate without any good reason to do so.  God I hated that site...

Answer (score 0):

If you must wait user some time and going on url then, you may add some code to your superAwesomeFunction's process end:

```
document.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
```